# Seattle Seahawks' Legion of Boom

Tags: american-football, trivia, history, terminology, nfl

I've heard commentators and analysts refer to Seattle Seahawks' defense as the "Legion of Boom". I believe they call the secondary that name, to be exact. What is the story behind this? When and how did this name start to be used to describe the Seahawks' secondary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_Boom_%28Seattle_Seahawks%29) and an [ESPN article](http://espn.go.com/nfl/playoffs/2013/story/_/id/10259323/nfl-playoffs-seattle-secondary-comes-first), the name "Legion of Boom" started when Seahawks safety Kam Chancellor appeared on the "Bob and Groz" radio show on 710 ESPN Seattle on August 2, 2012.

Kam Chancellor was back on the show on October 2, 2013, and they discussed the origin of "Legion of Boom".  You can hear the audio [here](http://www.kiroradio.com/listen/9962140/#).  At 42:17 in the audio, Bob/Groz say the following to Kam:

> Bob/Groz: "There's been a bit of controversy with the name 'Legion of Boom'.  I don't know if you're aware of this.  What I do know is that you're aware of where it started."

Then they played a snippet from the August 2, 2012 show:

> Bob/Groz: "What have you done in the offseason?"
>
> Kam: "I changed my diet up, just eating a lot cleaner, just eating chicken, fish, vegetables, fruit, trying to stay light to where I can run fast, but also still have a little weight to keep that boom."

Then back to Oct. 2, 2013:

> Bob/Groz: "Kam, we've always given you credit, we've said it started with you. That was August 2, 2012 on the Bob and Groz show.  Kam Chancellor started it."
>
> Kam: "It started on your show, yeah I remember saying 'the boom', the whole boom idea, and then it went to Twitter, and the 12th Man came up with 'Legion of Boom', and you know we just ran with it there.  But it definitely started on your show, with me saying 'boom'."